How to fix SQL Server Management Studio install on Windows 7 SP1?
I am learning SQL Server on my Windows 7 Laptop. And I am trying to install SQL Server Management Studio, I have already installed SQL Server Express and Local DB.
Whenever I try to install SSMS on my laptop, it freezes on ManagementToolsConfig_install_postmsi Cpu64 and I get this error

Cannot find one or more components. Please Reinstall the application

When I press OK, it continues with the setup, then it freezes again on ManagementAdvancedToolsConfig_install_postmsi Cpu64 and shows the same error.
Any help would be appreciated, if anybody wanted to ask about anything, just let me know.
I tried uninstalling SSMS and reinstalling it, there was still the same error, then I tried installing VS 2015 Shell, the error remained the same.

Which edition of Windows 7 is this?  Also are you installing the special version of SSMS that is built in to SQL Express, or do you mean the general version of SSMS?

Might seem silly, but perhaps it time to update to a supported operating system, and supported version of SQL Server. If you are learning SQL Server, learning a version that's end of life isn't a great choice (SQL Server 2014 wasn't a particularly well received version either).

Hmm, I haven't done this in a long time, but I seem to recall that you may need to install the SQL Server Configuration Manager client installation for your version of SQL Server first.  Not sure though...

The latest version SSMS version is 20.2, not 2014. Have you tried downloading and installing the latest version?

I don't think there's ever been a separate install for the Configuration manager, @RBarryYoung , certainly not since SQL Server 2008. In Windows 10 there was a period of time where it didn't show up in the start menu though, but that was a Windows "feature".

I cant install the latest SQL Server Because my Laptop is Win 7 @PanagiotisKanavos

SSMS <> SQL Server, @BaselAlaa . Though I admit, I'm not sure if SSMS 20 works on Windows 7 either. Like I said, you really shouldn't be using end of life software.

Windows 7 is no longer supported. You won't be able to install a recent version of SSMS. In fact, Windows 7 no longer gets security updates of any kind... even critical security patches. It's not safe to keep using it, and upgrading to a supported OS is job #1 here. (Keep in mind: Windows 10 will be in same place by November of next year). But also, those old versions you had to manually choose to run the installer as administrator for SQL Server stuff or they didn't work.

But I know that SQL Server 2014 can run on windows 7 @JoelCoehoorn

Sql server 2014 is the last version that runs on win 7,ask me how I know. Try to find the oldest ssms version you can install,theres a good page on Microsoft with older versions. Otherwise yeah, upgrade your comp

So is there no fix to the error?

@BaselAlaa Sure, but you'll need to find the version of SSMS from the same era. And even if you do find it, you're still doing something profoundly unsafe.

@JoelCoehoorn how can I find that?

@BaselAlaa go to the SSMS download page and look for a version older than 2020, the date Windows 7 reached End Of Life. It seems that's v17, last released in 2018. It may be possible to use v18 too.

@PanagiotisKanavos will this version work with SQL server 2014? Or to I need to upgrade it to a newer version

Why not try it out and come back with your findings?
